# Python for-loop counter error

Tags: python, for-loop, counter

I am attempting to script a short code to figure out the number of days it takes to reach a given principal in the bank due to daily interest. Using my code below does not yield any errors when run in IDLE, but the counter returns 0. Any ideas what I missed?

```
def main():
    # irrelevant code elided by msw, Bal, Int and Tar are numeric
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0):
        if (Bal * Int) == Tar:
            print '1'
        else:
            counter + 1
    print counter
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious but 'range(0)' is going to return an empty list, and your 'for' loop is never going to start.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt: for the benefit of those answering, it is best to post the minimal code that is required to demonstrate the failure (it may also help you see your own mistake).

Comment: Quite honestly I don't see how this program can possibly work. You are almost certainly never going to have bal*int exactly equal to tar. You need some sort of range. Also it looks like you balance is not accruing interest daily, so you are just doing the same comparison (Bal * Int) == Tar over and over again. Scrap the for or scrap the counter. Also it looks like you failed to make use of the hint(?) to use a math function (power function perhaps?)

Comment: 1st line of code: from math import *
It got edited out.

Comment: Your code is missing the most important thing: comments describing in English what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: I disagree. All the comments in the world won't make the code work any better. And if the code works and is well written it won't need any comments.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: "All the comments in the world won't make the code work any better" isn't the point.  The point is to get the questioner to actually describe what's supposed to be happening -- what they want to happen -- what they think *should* be happening.

Comment: @Bryan: The comments aren't to make the code work.  The comments are there to help some other folks (read: us) make the code work.  And code that works and is well written may still need comments, for example to clarify any tricks in use, or to clarify *why* a particular algorithm is being used.

Comment: @S.Lott, et. al: Obviously my comments (pun not intended) were misinterpreted. Mike said the *code* was missing comments, I meant to point out that the comments he speaks of don't belong in the *code*. Code comments, as Mike DeSimone correctly says, are for describing the _why_ of an algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you're getting at with this loop:

```
for i in range(0):
    if (Bal * Int) == Tar:
        print '1'
    else:
        counter + 1
```

1. `range(0)` is an empty list, so the loop won't execute at all.
2. `counter + 1` simply calculates one more than counter, it won't increment counter, you probably mean `counter += 1`
3. There's nothing in the loop that changes at each iteration, so if you ever get into it, it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Essentially, I am using the counter to try and generate the number of days needed to reach the target (Tar) balance in the account.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt: "I am using the counter to try and generate the number of days needed".  No, you're not.  Read the answer.  That loop does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the formula to calculate final balance with interest is:

```
Final = Principal * ( 1 + interest ) ** interest_period
```

Assuming I got this correct, then you can find out how many interest periods it will take by:

```
def how_long(start_money, interest_rate, final_money):
    day = 0
    money = start_money
    while True:
        if money >= final_money:
            break
        day += 1
        money = start_money * (1 + interest_rate)**day

    return day, money
```

Comment: Instead of the "while True:/if not condition:/break" caper, consider `while money < final_money:`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [5]: def test():
   ...:     for i in range(0):
   ...:         return '1'
   ...:     
   ...:     

In [6]: x = test()

In [7]: print x
------> print(x)
None
```

See the return value is 'None'.
I don't know what are you trying to do. But The basic mistake is the Argument of range(x) function. The range(0) always return empty list.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you put range(0) which is an empty loop. Perhaps you could consider a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop `for i in range(0)` doesn't actually execute.  `range(0)` returns an empty list `[]` which will skip the body of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what you think this does?  Please update your question with an English-language explanation of how many times you think this look will work.

```
counter = 0
for i in range(0):
    if (Bal * Int) == Tar:
        print '1'
    else:
        counter + 1
```

Hint.  The answer is zero.  The question is "why?"  and "what were you trying to do?"

Answer (score 0):

You have been told the three or more problems with your code. If there's no particular reason to use a loop, it's better calculated with a formula:

```
future_value = present_value * (1 + interest_rate_per_period) ** number_of periods
```

or, for short,

```
f = p * (1 + i) ** n
f / p = (1 + i) ** n
log(f / p) = n * log(1 + i)
n = log(f / p) / log(i + i)
```

Example: I have $5000; how many years will it take to grow to $10000 at 10% per annum?

```
>>> from math import log
>>> f = 10000.0
>>> p = 5000.0
>>> i = 0.1
>>> n = log(f / p) / log(1 + i)
>>> n
7.272540897341713
>>>
```